# Comparing User Input To Data Generated Randomly

Tags: python, random, compare

I've written a python cgi script to generate random numbers and add them together
than ask the user to give the answer.

But even user answer was correct, it gives him wrong. The answer will not be correct.
The problem is in the flow :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi,sys,random

sys.stderr = sys.stdout

input_field = cgi.FieldStorage()

x = random.randrange(1,20)
y = random.randrange(1,20)

answer = x + y

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print ("<center>")

if "input" in input_field:

    if input_field["input"].value == answer:
        print("Content-Type content=text/htm")
        print "<br><br><b> Good :D </b"
    else:

        print "<br><br><b> Wrong :( </b><br><br>"
        print "Your Answer :",input_field['input'].value
        print "<br>","Correct Answer",answer
else:

    print "<br><br>",x,"+",y,"<br><br>"
    print("""

<form method=POST action="">
<TR>
<TH align=right>Answer:<TD>
<input type=text name=input>
<TR>

""")

print ("</center>")
```

e.g :

---

> 3 + 9
>
> Answer: [12                    ]

---

> **Wrong :(**
>
> Your Answer : 12
>   Correct Answer 17

Has anyone know what should I do to fix the flow? **It generate new numbers each time**

**Note : This is not a type error, it's *Logical* error**

Answer (score 0):

```
if input_field["input"].value == answer:
```

try this instead:

```
if input_field["input"].value.strip() == str(answer):
```

Your script generates new numbers each time you call it:

1. First call, random numbers generated and shown
2. Second call, new random numbers generated and compared to what the user enters (his answer is based on previously generated numbers).

One possibility (if you consider a user, who does not tweak with the web page source) would be to write the random numbers generated in the first step into `<input type="hidden" name="x" value="123"/>` tags, and take them into account when evaluating the answer.

Comment: Thank you but this isn't the problem, the problem is that the data keep changing and the user will not answer the right answer because the question has been changed

Comment: @Barakat - see my answer now. Your numbers are re-generated each time the script is called.

Answer (score 0):

If cgi.FieldStorage() is a string -> string mapping, you have to convert the input:

```
try:
    # first cast the string to an int
    user_input = int(input_field["input"].value)
except ValueError:
   # string 
   print("you must enter an integer")
if user_input == answer:
    print("Content-Type content=text/htm")
    print "<br><br><b> Good :D </b"
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem, it's a logic problem

Answer (score 0):

You generate a new question and answer before checking the user input.

You should store the question and/or answer in the user's session (on the server side so the user can't cheat) and use that to compare with the input.